# How to reset keyboard settings

Tags: keyboard

I was trying to remap my keyboard using `xmodmap`, edited the `xkb` file and now the keyboard completely stopped working.

So the exact steps were go to terminal, `sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc`, edited the file, saved it, i guess I made a typo or some mistake. Then I typed in `rm -rf /var/lib/xkb/*` and restarted. Now it says no x keyboard found, even the on screen keyboard data that.

How can I reset the file to its original state?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question with the exact path of all the files you edited? You/I could get you a copy from a fresh install of those.

Comment: Okay I edited it in.

Comment: You can replace the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` with [this one](https://mega.nz/#!xc4nwQIQ!Kd6as-zq-AzcNuIfRsYg1v1PF36J66TX_i3PywwIR10)

Comment: Did you try something?